# Demora en ejecucion procedimiento sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo un procedimiento que me trae resultado de 26 BD distintas, el query si lo ejecuto en una sola base de datos se me demora aprox 5 segundos, pero si ejecuto el procedimiento completo, llega a las 2 horas y me toca cancelarlo, alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

aclaro que este codigo solo es de con 2 BD porque se haria muy extenso el codigo, muchas gracias!

```
USE [Porcisoft_Cliente_PDV0]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Informe_Cartera_PV]    Script Date: 14/03/2019 09:43:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Informe_Cartera_PRUE] @Year  NVARCHAR(18)

AS
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#Cartera]
     ([codigo]        [CHAR](30)      NULL, 
      [Codbodega]     [CHAR](30)      NULL,
      [NombreCliente] [NVARCHAR](200) NULL,
      [Consecutivo]   [CHAR](20)      NULL, 
      [Fecha]         [DATETIME]      NULL, 
      [Fechavence]    [DATETIME]      NULL, 
      [codtipodcto]   [NVARCHAR](5)   NULL,
      [Totalgeneral]  [NUMERIC](20,2) NULL,
      [SaldoFactura]  [NUMERIC](20,2) NULL,       
     )
     ON [PRIMARY];

--Apartado
INSERT INTO #Cartera

SELECT FA0.Codigo,FA0.codbodega,RTRIM (FA0.nombre )+' '+ RTRIM(FA0.Nombre1) +' '+RTRIM( FA0.Apellido)+' '+RTRIM(FA0.Apellido1) as Nombrecliente,FA0.Consecutivo,FA0.Fecha,FA0.Fechavence,FA0.codtipodcto,FA0.Totalgeneral,
(FA0.Totalgeneral-((IsNull(AB0.Valor,0)+IsNull(AB0.Retencion,0)))) as Saldo
FROM (
SELECT S0.Nombre,S0.Nombre1,S0.Apellido,S0.Apellido1,S0.Telefono1,S0.EsCliente,S0.EsEmpleado,
       F0.tiporeferencia,F0.Codigo,F0.consecutivo,F0.Referencia,F0.Fecha,F0.Fechavence,F0.codtipodcto,F0.Totalgeneral,F0.codbodega
FROM APTDPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencfacturas F0 INNER JOIN APTDPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios S0 ON F0.codigo=S0.codigo
WHERE F0.Fecha<=CONVERT(datetime,@Year))AS FA0 LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT A1.codtipodcto,A0.Codigo,A1.Factura,SUM(A1.Valor)AS Valor,SUM(A1.Retencion)AS Retencion
FROM APTDPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencabonosfactura A0 INNER JOIN APTDPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoabonosfactura A1 ON A0.documento=A1.documento
WHERE A0.Fecha<=CONVERT(datetime,@Year)
GROUP BY  A1.codtipodcto,A0.Codigo,A1.Factura) AB0 ON FA0.consecutivo=AB0.factura AND FA0.codtipodcto=AB0.codtipodcto
WHERE FA0.codtipodcto <> 'FAP' AND FA0.tiporeferencia<>'FAP' AND FA0.Totalgeneral-(Isnull(AB0.Valor,0)+IsNull(AB0.Retencion,0)) NOT BETWEEN -1 AND 1

--Bogota
INSERT INTO #Cartera

SELECT FA0.Codigo,FA0.codbodega,RTRIM (FA0.nombre )+' '+ RTRIM(FA0.Nombre1) +' '+RTRIM( FA0.Apellido)+' '+RTRIM(FA0.Apellido1) as Nombrecliente,FA0.Consecutivo,FA0.Fecha,FA0.Fechavence,FA0.codtipodcto,FA0.Totalgeneral,
(FA0.Totalgeneral-((IsNull(AB0.Valor,0)+IsNull(AB0.Retencion,0)))) as Saldo
FROM (
SELECT S0.Nombre,S0.Nombre1,S0.Apellido,S0.Apellido1,S0.Telefono1,S0.EsCliente,S0.EsEmpleado,
       F0.tiporeferencia,F0.Codigo,F0.consecutivo,F0.Referencia,F0.Fecha,F0.Fechavence,F0.codtipodcto,F0.Totalgeneral,F0.codbodega
FROM BCOPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencfacturas F0 INNER JOIN BCOPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios S0 ON F0.codigo=S0.codigo
WHERE F0.Fecha<=CONVERT(datetime,@Year))AS FA0 LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT A1.codtipodcto,A0.Codigo,A1.Factura,SUM(A1.Valor)AS Valor,SUM(A1.Retencion)AS Retencion
FROM BCOPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencabonosfactura A0 INNER JOIN BCOPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoabonosfactura A1 ON A0.documento=A1.documento
WHERE A0.Fecha<=CONVERT(datetime,@Year)
GROUP BY  A1.codtipodcto,A0.Codigo,A1.Factura) AB0 ON FA0.consecutivo=AB0.factura AND FA0.codtipodcto=AB0.codtipodcto
WHERE FA0.codtipodcto <> 'FAP' AND FA0.tiporeferencia<>'FAP' AND FA0.Totalgeneral-(Isnull(AB0.Valor,0)+IsNull(AB0.Retencion,0)) NOT BETWEEN -1 AND 1

select * from #Cartera
```

el codigo es el mismo para los otros 24 puntos que se van agregando abajo, solo cambia la BD, pero por mas que busco no encuentro la razon de la demora en la ejecucion

Comment: No se si ya lo has realizado, pero verificaste el plan de ejecución y las estadisticas de tú consulta? eso te ayuda a encontrar los cuellos de botella en tu transacción

Comment: no, nunca habia escuchado eso, como puedo mirarlo?